# How to make far left column sticky for horizontal row scrolling in a list with JSON column formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

I would like to make the far left column sticky so that it remains in view when scrolling horizontally on a list with many columns. This is also my Title column. Can this be accomplished with the JSON Column formatting? This would be the simplest method I could think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, for now there is no way to freeze the first column in SharePoint Online Modern List. Json Formatting is not able to do that. You may post in [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration) for this feature.